When to set a dependencies to optional in Rust cargo.toml?
I am a novice of Rust and try to read some projects for studying. In this Binance API connector Rust library, some dependencies are set to be optional but others not.
[features]
default = ["enable-ureq", "enable-tungstenite"]
enable-hyper = [ "hyper", "hyper-tls", "serde_json", "futures-util", "tokio" ]
enable-ureq = [ "ureq", "serde_json" ]
enable-tungstenite = ["tungstenite"]
enable-tokio-tungstenite = ["tokio-tungstenite"]
full = ["enable-hyper", "enable-tungstenite", "enable-ureq", "enable-tokio-tungstenite"]

[dependencies]
hmac = "0.12.0"
log = "0.4.14"
serde = { version = "1.0.136", features = ["derive"] }
sha2 = { version = "0.10.6", default-features = false, features = ["oid"] }
url = "2.2.2"
rust_decimal = "1.24.0"
http = "0.2.7"
strum = { version = "0.24", features = ["derive"] }
rand = "0.8.5"
signature = "2.2.0"
base64 = "0.13.1"
ed25519-dalek = { version = "2.1.0", features = ["serde", "zeroize", "rand_core", "digest", "pkcs8", "pem"] }

# enable-ureq
ureq = { version = "2.4.0", optional = true }

# enable-hyper
hyper = { version = "0.14.16", features = ["full"], optional = true }
serde_json = { version = "1.0.78", optional = true }
hyper-tls = {version = "0.5.0", optional = true }
futures-util = {version = "0.3.21", optional = true }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["time"], optional = true }

# enable-tungstenite
tungstenite = {version = "0.20.1", features = ["native-tls"], optional = true}

# enable-tokio-tungstenite
tokio-tungstenite = {version = "0.17.1", features = ["native-tls"], optional = true}

What is the considerations that some dependencies should be set to optional while others not?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#optional-dependencies

Optional dependencies are not compiled unless enabled by a feature.
You can see above a set of [features] for this crate ("enable-hyper", "enable-ureq", etc.) where the default features are automatically enabled unless disabled (via default-features = false in dependent crate or --no-default-features argument when building locally). The authors here were kind enough to group the optional = true dependencies separately and even with a heading comment documenting which features enable them.

When to set a dependency as optional?

You should only set them as optional if there are parts of your crate that you don't wish to compile unless that part is desired. Leaving dependencies optional means the end-user can avoid downloading and building these dependencies if they don't use what they're there for.
Third-party library support (hyper, ureq, etc.) is a good use of features and optional dependencies.
You shouldn't do this needlessly though since the code in the package that does rely on those optional dependencies need to be feature-gated to ensure they aren't compiled when the dependency isn't there. Over-use may end up unmaintainable. For example, if there is such a function exposed by this library that uses the ureq crate it may be written with conditional compilation annotations like this:
#[cfg(feature = "enable-ureq")]
pub fn use_ureq() {
    use ureq::*; // the ureq dependency is available here

    ...
}

Thus if a dependent user doesn't enable the "enable-ureq" feature (or leave it as default in this case), then they won't be able to call the use_ureq function.
There's another potential burden if your features aren't well segregated: it may be hard to test that all combinations of enabled features are actually compilable. See the Q&A here for help on that.
